# DOM - вывести текст с тегом

Tags: php

Пример: Текст`<span>1</span>`

```
$text = $node->textContent;
```

выводит

Текст1

Как вывести Текст`<span>1</span>` полностью с тегом?

Comment: `$node->outerHTML`/`$node->outerXml`

Comment: Пусто стало....

Comment: что это за код, и что это за переменные?

Comment: Укажите каким именно инструментом(библиотекой) вы пользуетесь